# PHP: Simple way to substr_count() where substring is array

Tags: php, arrays, substring

I have a range of letters in an array:

```
$myRange = range("a","c");
```

I want to count how many times the letters in this range appear in a string:

```
$str = "abcdefg";
```

Is there a way I could use `substr_count()` to achieve this?

Eg: `substr_count($str, $myRange);`

I could use a foreach loop, but that seems overkill and not as elegant. Are loops the only way?

Comment: how about `count_chars()` then use your array to pick the values you care about -if stings are large this may be a bad idea, but worth benchmarking

Comment: I don't see why a loop would be so bad. But you can use `count_chars()` as already mentioned and then get the intersect with only the chars which you want. You can also do this with `array_count_values()` if you split the string first into an array.

Comment: You could also use `array_reduce` with an anonymous function that calls `substr_count`... but that's either gonna require a `global $str;`, which is ugly, or some kind of wrapper, which is certainly "more overkill" than a loop. E.g. `$count = array_reduce($myRange, function($c, $i){global $str; return $c + substr_count($str, $i);});`

Comment: `array_intersect_key(array_count_values(str_split($str)), array_flip($myRange));`

Comment: codegolf array function incantation one liners

Comment: @Ghost And what is a one-liner in codegolf? A "hole-in-one"? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using only single chars, you can use:

```
count( array_intersect( str_split( $str ), $myRange ) );
```

But foreach is 3x faster..

Comment: Sure. Made a simple microtime(true) benchmark on 1000000 loops.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a regex:

```
preg_match_all("/[a-c]/", "aaabbbcccddasdfasdf", $match);
$array = array();
foreach($match[0] as $val)
{
    if(!isset($array[$val]))
    {
        $array[$val] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $array[$val] += 1;
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

and it'll give you, as a key-value array

```
Array
(
    [a] => 5
    [b] => 3
    [c] => 3
)
```